# How to solve the following recursive formula?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I am very new to recursion and have no idea how to solve the following problem.

$n \geq 1$ is a power of 2 integer

$T(1) = 0$

$T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + n$

Can someone please explain to me how to do this? If you can kindly work it as example, I will be able to do the other problems. Thanks. Below is what I attempted

Using the master theorem

$a = 2$
$b = 2$
$d = 1$

$d = log_2 2 $

Hence my answer is $\Theta(n\log n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T(n) = 2(2T(\frac{n}{4}) + \frac{n}{2}) + n = 2^2 T(\frac{n}{4}) + 2n $$

By expanding the equation you can get:
$$T(n) = 2^nT(1) + n\times(\log(n)-1) = n\log(n) - n$$

Comment: Is this the substitution method? I think I was able to solve it using the master theorem. Please see my edits. Thanks btw.

Comment: @Avi You can just the complexity and upper bound using master theorem. Although, this method is part of master method, but gives you an exact solution.